# Null Pointer Dereference issue not detected when the pointer is returned by another function

Tags: c, pointers, sonarqube, cppcheck

I use SonarQube (5.1 with cppecheck 1.70) to analyse C-code.
In following example, there is a Null Pointer Dereference issue that should be detected by SonarQube and/or Cppcheck (used by Sonar). But no issue found by SonarQube niether repported by Cppcheck.

```
struct s1
{ 
    char c1;
    char c2;
};

struct s1 * toto1(void)
{ 
    return NULL;
}

void toto2(void)
{ 
    struct s1* my_st=NULL;
    my_st = toto1();
    my_st->c1 = 1;
    my_st->c2 = 0;
    return;
}
```

Is there any restriction on this rule (Null pointers should not be dereferenced) in such situation?

Comment: this is completely `C`, don't add `C++` to it

Comment: @CppNITR: Considering `cppcheck` is used, the C++ tag is understandable - but indeed wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I am a Cppcheck developer.

I was surprised that Cppcheck does not detect that.

I have created this ticket upstream:
http://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/7132

Thank you! Let me know if you discover more false negatives.

Answer (score 0):

SonarCube does static code analysis. This is a runtime failure.

To see why this is a problem for static analysis, see the following modification:

```
struct s1 * toto1(void)
{
    MightHalt(); /* good luck with your static analysis */ 
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: MightHalt is a red herring. Static analysis should catch that.

Comment: @this: In case you weren't aware, it's a reference to the Halting Problem. Static analysis _can't_ catch it, and that's a mathematical fact.

Comment: I think I phrased the comment poorly. Let me fix that: MightHalt is a red herring as far as this question is concerned. Static analysis should catch the example SaidSsu presented. You don't provide an answer to this question.

Answer (score -1):

A NULL pointer is not a pointer that points to the memory location `0` or something else. It is simply a pointer that *points to nothing*. It's just a special pointer that doesn't point to anything valid.

According to `C`, a NULL pointer should not be dereferenced. Although it does not say what should happen if it is dereferenced.

Comment: True, but that's not the question. SonarCube is a tool to find errors, this is an obvious error, why doesn't it find the error?