# Sonar: Null pointers should not be dereferenced

Tags: java, sonarqube

False-positives are pointed out in other SO posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40047851/sonar-false-positive-on-rule-null-pointers-should-not-be-dereferenced) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693468/null-pointer-dereference-issue-not-detected-when-the-pointer-is-returned-by-anot)), where `nulls` are involved across functions and procedures.

I feel my situation is not as complicated.

```
    // A and B are both Double[]

    if (A.length == 1 || (B != null && B.length == 1)) {
        Double vol;
        if (A.length == 1) {
            vol = A[0];
        } else {
            vol = B[0]; // Sonar Blocker: Null pointers should not be deferenced
        }
    }
```

I could've fixed this by changing `else` to `else if (B != null && B.length == 1)`, but doing so rewards me with warning "condition`(B != null && B.length == 1)` is always true".

Did I miss something here?

Comment: which version of SonarQube are you using? Which version of SonarJava plugin do you have?

Comment: @Tibor SonarQube version 5.6.6, IntelliJ SonarLint plugin 3.0.0.2041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code is ok.**

When B is null, The control reaches inside the main if block only when length of A is 1. But when length of A is 1, the control never reaches the else block.

PS: I also tried the code in android studio which uses Lint and got no warnings.